# Multiplying array columns by vector

Tags: arrays, r, vector, multiplication

I'm new to R and I am certain that this is simple yet I can't seem to find an answer. I have an array [36,21,12012], and I need to multiply all of the columns by a vector of the same length to create a new array of the same dimensions.

Comment: Please, give us a full example of what you want: two vectors and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `v` is your vector and `a` is your array, in your case it would be as simple as `v * a`, because arrays are built column-wise. But in general, you would use `sweep`. For example to multiply along the rows, `sweep(a, MARGIN=2, STATS=v, FUN='*')`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, appreciate your help!